# When ı want edit values in my table ı can't save new information. How can ı solve this fındIndex error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create contact form .Also this form has a table and I am trying to edit and save informations from table. I did everthing but my save button is not working. When ı click to save button, the consol give me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findIndex')"

```
const EditRow = () => {
const {AddFormData,setAddFormData, editFormData, handleEditFormChange, handleCancelClick } = useContext(GlobalContext);
const [editContactId, setEditContactId] = useState(null);

const handleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const editedContact = {
        id: editContactId,
        fullName: editFormData.fullName,
        email: editFormData.email,
        phoneNumber: editFormData.phoneNumber,
        country: editFormData.country,

    };

    const newAddFormData = [...AddFormData];
console.log(AddFormData)

    const index = AddFormData.findIndex((formData) => formData.id === editContactId);

    newAddFormData[index] = editedContact;

    setAddFormData(newAddFormData);
    setEditContactId(null);
```

[image]

Comment: And when you do "console.log(AddFormData)" you have an array ?

Comment: yes, I have. I can see all input informations to console

Comment: The error is more than clear its `undefind` in some point of the time or maybe always... also not sure what exactly is `AddFormData` but is not a react component in my opinion and should not be with upper case, you should trace the problem, take a look inside the context as well and maybe privide us with some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use findIndex on **nedwAddFormData** which is the copy of **AddFormData**. ?